# SSL Socket Factory Error

Tags: java, android, sockets, email, ssl

I'm new to Android Studio and i built an application that reads from the email and extract data from it, it keeps showing that I have an error with the SSL Socket Factory, I've searched a lot and nothing seems to be working, in the manifest I added the permission for internet and tried to change the port number to 143 instead of 993, but it's still the same, if anyone can help me please.

```
public class EmailManager {
    private String stmpHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String mailServer = "imap.gmail.com";
    private EmailAccount account;
    Session smtpSession;
    private Session imapSession;
    private Folder inbox;
    public Store store;
    public String from="xxx@gmail.com";
    public String sub ="100";
    public String FName, LName,Age, appDate, Loc, All, Med, refby;
    public int lineNumber = 0;
    BufferedReader br;
    public InputStream is;
    String sCurrentLine = null;
    String next = " ";
    Date datetime;
    String[] info;
    Context context;
    DBHandler dbHandler;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;


    public EmailManager(String username, String password, String stmpHost, String mailServer) {
        account = new EmailAccount(username, password);
        this.stmpHost = stmpHost;
        this.mailServer = mailServer;
        initProtocol();
    }
    private void initProtocol() {
        EmailAuthenticator authenticator = new EmailAuthenticator(account);

        Properties props1 = new Properties();  
        props1.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "smtps");
        props1.setProperty("mail.host", stmpHost);  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  
        props1.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");  
        smtpSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props1, authenticator); 

        Properties props2 = new Properties();
        props2.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "imaps");
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", mailServer);
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
            imapSession = Session.getInstance(props2);
    }   
    public Message[] getMails() throws Exception {
        store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(mailServer, account.username, account.password);
        inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] result = inbox.getMessages();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

            //print subjects of all mails in the inbox
            {
                if(result[i].getFrom().toString() == from && result[i].getSubject()==sub){
                    try {
                        result[i].getContent().toString();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    LineReader();
                    saveData();
                }

            }

        }

        return result;
    }

    public void LineReader() throws Exception {

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        appDate = df.format(datetime);

        try{
            if (!(is instanceof BufferedInputStream)) {
                is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            }


            while((next = br.readLine()) != null){
                sCurrentLine = next;
                lineNumber++;
            }


            if (sCurrentLine != null) {
                info = sCurrentLine.split(",");

            }
            FName = info[0];
            LName = info[1];
            Age = info[2];
            appDate = info[3];
            Loc = info[4];
            Med = info[5];
            All = info[6];
            refby = info[7];
        }
        catch (IOException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                if (br !=null)br.close();

            }catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveData() {

        String FirstName = FName;
        String LastName = LName;
        String age = Age;
        String Location = Loc;
        String Medicine = Med;
        String Allergies = All;
        String Referredby = refby;
        java.sql.Date DatenTime = java.sql.Date.valueOf(appDate)  ;

        Emails em = new Emails();
        em.setFName(FirstName);
        em.setLName(LastName);
        em.setAge(age);
        em.setDatetime(DatenTime);
        em.setLoc(Location);
        em.setMed(Medicine);
        em.setAll(Allergies);
        em.setRefby(Referredby);
        dbHandler = new DBHandler(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        dbHandler.addEmail(em, sqLiteDatabase);
        dbHandler.close();


    }

    public void close() {
        //Close connection 
        try {
            inbox.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }}
```

**Error**

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Couldn't connect using "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" socket factory to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; Exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException;

01-27 09:54:03.712 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:   nested exception is:
01-27 09:54:03.712 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:  java.io.IOException: Couldn't connect using "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" socket factory to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; Exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:571)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at com.mbp.doctorshelper.EmailManager.getMails(EmailManager.java:76)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at com.mbp.doctorshelper.AppsList$1.run(AppsList.java:68)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-27 09:54:03.716 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't connect using "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" socket factory to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; Exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:178)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:107)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:104)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:538)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:  ... 11 more
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err: Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:305)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:100)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:85)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:163)
01-27 09:54:03.717 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:  ... 14 more
```

Comment: javax.mail.MessagingException: Couldn't connect using "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" socket factory to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; Exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException;
01-27 09:54:03.712 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:   nested exception is:
01-27 09:54:03.712 11463-11463/com.mbp.doctorshelper W/System.err:  java.io.IOException: Couldn't connect using "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" socket factory to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; Exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Can you post the full exception in code formatting?

Comment: the tread is created in a second activity not in the main, the main contain log in stuffs, to enter email and password those used for Emailmanager to get inbox data